# Is there a way to reduce the count of the dex file in Android？

Tags: android, performance, gradle, gradle-plugin

[image]

As shown above, my app has many dex files. Then in the process of application startup speed optimization, bindApplication used to have many io-blocks.

[image]

[image]

I think it may be that there are too many dex files causing the io-block above, causing my app to start very slowly. So I want to compress these dex files. Is there a way to achieve this, please?

project structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the app and build configurations you enabled.

What you can start with is to enable [R8 optimizations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) that would enable shrink code and remove unused code from the app.

If you have everything as part of your app, you may consider moving some features into [dynamic feature modules](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery) that would be installed on demand.

Although many dex files can have effect on app startup time, verify it really is the bottleneck. You can optimize app startup with [Baseline Profiles](http://d.android.com/baseline-profiles) that can pre-compile parts of your app into machine code, which significantly increases app startup time (and runtime performance).